# Anaconda Python Library with QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, opencv

I'm currently thinking about ways to develop scripts with `openCV` library and use with QGIS.
I've installed python directly from `Anaconda` distribution and installed new packages from it (never had a problem with anaconda, and in fact I love it).

I wonder that the python from QGIS is installed directly from QGIS, and not from other sources in my computer.

Is there a way that I can link QGIS Python to Anacondas packages or Do I need to install 'new' packages for QGIS?

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis

Comment: https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/installing-python-packages-in-qgis-3-for-windows/

Comment: @raulindo, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley I still haven't tried. I'll do it next week!